# How to remove extension in eclipse through programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have created an extension point, and i am trying to implement that extension in some other plugin. After certain point of time i need to remove that extension in runtime. So currentlt i am using the below to code(Reflection call)

My Code Here :

```java
IExtensionRegistry reg = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
Field privateStringField = ExtensionRegistry.class.getDeclaredField("masterToken"); //$NON-NLS-1$
privateStringField.setAccessible(true);
Object masterToken = privateStringField.get(reg);
IConfigurationElement[] config = reg.getConfigurationElementsFor("com.temp.rcp.product");
for (IConfigurationElement configElement : config) {
    if (configElement.getAttribute("name").equals("Temp")) {
        reg.removeExtension(configElement.getDeclaringExtension(), masterToken);
    }
}
```

I looked into the code and found a solution, but this is totally not acceptable, because it could/will break, when i update my eclipse target platform, because of the reflection call.

Can anyone of you help me to solve the above issue.

Comment: There is no support for this. Why do you think you need to remove the extension?

Comment: I have two products regarding my development phase, but plugins are same for both products. One of the product i don't want to use this implementation. That's why i wanted to remove this extension during runtime.

Comment: Why not just set a flag the code can test to say it is disabled. Looking at the main Eclipse source nothing at all uses `removeExtension`.

Comment: If you haven't already read it also see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-API-Use/index.html) which rules out using `ExtensionRegistry` as it is in an internal package.

Comment: As the one who's providing the extension point, you already have complete control over which extensions you do and do not interact with. You don't need to forcibly remove an extension from the registry since nothing else would interact with the extensions anyway.